# How to change the background to match the user's weather conditions and time of day?

Tags: javascript

So far my code is working, but only for the day time photos. I forgot to put in night time photos for the user's location. So when it says good evening and the weather condition says clear sky, then the background should change to a clear sky and a night time photo not a sunny photo like I have already. How can I change my background to the user's weather by location and their time of day? This is a link to my codepen just incase you would like to see it in action. https://codepen.io/Brown95/pen/MvvBLK

```
var weatherImage = "";

  var imagePhoto = {

    thunder: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2e/43/73/2e4373184057ab029b5ca15aca484b09.jpg",
    rainy: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/q76bMs-NwRk/maxresdefault.jpg",
    cloudy: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57523357c2ea515ccf6c1adb/58dcea75bebafb06e997da9c/58dcece61e5b6cf38585d46b/1490873606398/mostly+cloudy.jpg",
    snow: "https://static.bhphotovideo.com/explora/sites/default/files/Correct.jpg",
    clear: "https://mota.ru/upload/wallpapers/2010/05/14/08/01/22099/mota_ru_0051405-2560x1600.jpg",
    drizzle: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e4/43/f5/e443f59b4f03dd487d090a279c2f08ab--rain-drops-water-drops.jpg",
    haze: "https://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3578564/thumb/1.jpg",
    tornado: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5QnsRXUbsK4/maxresdefault.jpg",
    cold: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/374/snow-dawn-sunset-winter.jpg",
    windy: "https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/4337360/thumb/1.jpg",
    hail: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/7c/60/3d/7c603d9183ff32c92330780a2ebdcfca--rainy-weather-rainy-days.jpg",
    sunny: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rG9fev-m0ag/maxresdefault.jpg"
};


function selectImage (id){

    if (id >= 200 && id <= 232){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.thunder;
    }else if(id >= 300 && id <= 321){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.drizzle;
    }else if (id >= 500 && id <= 531){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.rainy;
    }else if (id >= 600 && id <= 622){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.snow;
    }else if (id >= 701 && id <= 721 ){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.haze;
    }else if (id === 800){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.clear;
    }else if (id >= 801 && id <= 804){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.cloudy;
    }else if (id >= 900 && id <= 902){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.tornado;
    }else if (id === 903){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.cold;
    }else if (id === 904){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.sunny;
    }else if (id === 905){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.windy;
    }else if (id === 906){
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.hail;
    }else{
        weatherImage = imagePhoto.windy;
    }

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + weatherImage + ')');


}
```

Comment: The quesiton is, can you know what's the weather in their location?

Comment: No, I already know how to get the weather and change the background to match their weather. I'm just asking if it is night time and it is a clear sky then the picture of the moon should show with a clear sky, not a picture of the sun with a clear sky. You know?

Comment: Answered with the function to let you get current datetime

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the current DateTime:

```js
console.log(new Date());
```

On w3c you will find many functions to retrive specific data from the date:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: I used the get date in my code already. I will check, hold on. I use w3schools all the time it is so helpful by the way.

Comment: This command retrive local information, so every user will send you his own datetime and you will be able to set the right image

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Mark the answer if it helped you ^^

Comment: Do I put the backgrounds in the if/else statement of the hours?

Comment: You have to use the same way you were doing with the morning skies, just put there an if that check for the local time and if it's morning chooses one or if it's night chooses the other one

Comment: Ok, so I should use another if/else statement for the night time, based on the hours, it won't override anything will it and change the other photos?